# Caesar Cipher encryption VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make an encryption method in VB.net.
I plan to use arrays so you input the value and it then compares two arrays changing the value.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please input text")
    Dim UserInput As String = Console.ReadLine
    UserInput = UserInput.ToUpper()
    Console.WriteLine("Original Input is " & UserInput)

    Dim EncriptedText As String
    Dim Numbers() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"}
    Dim Letters() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " "}


    For counter As Integer = 0 To UserInput.Length - 1
        Dim pos As Integer = Array.IndexOf(Numbers, UserInput.Chars(counter))
        Dim CharValue As Char = Letters.ElementAt(pos)
        UserInput = UserInput + CharValue
        Console.WriteLine(UserInput)
    Next

    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

It throws an error when I try to run it.
Does anyone have any idea how I could fix it?

> Error : Found on The Dim CharValue As Char Line
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I was thinking it could be because I am trying to convert numbers to chars and if so what other methods could I use?

Comment: Why do you want to implement such a **weak** encryption algorithm?

Comment: ***Dont roll your own encryption*** at least for anything sensitive as many things can go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

1) You are using the wrong array to get the index of a letter, and so the wrong array to get its enciphered value.

2) When you use `Array.IndexOf` like that, you need to give it a string to look for rather than a char. In your code, it is returning -1 because it didn't find the char in the array of strings (once the correct array is used).

3) You're modifying the input string in the loop, I guess you meant to use a separate variable for it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input text")
Dim userInput As String = Console.ReadLine()
userInput = userInput.ToUpper()
Console.WriteLine("Original input is " & userInput)

Dim numbers() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"}
Dim letters() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " "}

Dim encryptedText As String = ""

For counter As Integer = 0 To userInput.Length - 1
    Dim pos As Integer = Array.IndexOf(letters, (userInput.Chars(counter)))
    Dim cipherValue As String = numbers.ElementAt(pos)
    encryptedText = encryptedText & cipherValue
    Console.WriteLine(encryptedText)
Next

Console.Read()
```

Please note that it is usual to start variable names with a lowercase letter.

Now that you can get output, you can go on to find the other problems with the code :)